# Javascript ""Function not found"

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a very simple HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test 2 V2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <label id="wordCat"></label>
        <input type="text" id="txtCat">
        <input type="button" id="btnCat" value="Load Word" onclick="fetchData(document.getElementById('txtCat').value)">
    </p> 
    <p>
        <label>Your Guess Word is:</label>
        <label id="hiddenWord"></label>
    </p>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

On clicking the button it should call the function:

```
async function fetchData(req) {
    console.log(req.value)
    let response = await fetch(req);
    var selectBox, option, prop;

    

    selectBox = document.getElementById("drivers");

    if (response.statusText == "OK") {
        return await response.json();      
    }else{
        throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I click the button it says: `GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/{input value in the text box} 404 (Not Found)`

Anyone can help me fixing this? This method is supposed to load all the keys present in json file and print them.

words.json

```
{
    "sports":       ["golf", "hockey", "football"],
    "animals":      ["giraffe", "snake", "lizard", "puma"],
    "video games":  ["pacman", "asteroids", "super mario brothers", "donkey kong"]
}
```

I need to print the keys in alphabetical order on HTML page.

Thanks.

Comment: Besides the syntax error(s), you just should not be using in-line event handlers in this way.

Comment: You're making an ajax get request to that endpoint, and your browser is telling you that endpoint doesn't exist. What API routes, if any, have you set up on your server? It sounds like you're missing them, and need to do some research into setting up API routes for the server technology you're using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to attach the click event listener to the button in the script page.

```
document.getElementById('btnCat').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    const value = document.getElementById('txtCat').value;
    fetchData(value);
});
```